# Best way to put variables in a Textview?

Tags: android, variables, textview

I try to put one or more variables in a `TextView`.
For exemple :
Hello I am a "girl" and I live in "Boston"

I would like to know what is the best way to do it :

> 1. Can i do it directly in the `layout` file ?
> 2. Can i do it only via Java Class ?
> 3. Can i do it via `values/styles.xml` ?

For now i do it like this :

```
String text1 = "Hello I am a ";
String text2 =" and I live in ";
String var1= preferences.getString("sex", "null");
String var2= preferences.getString("city", "null");
TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
Text.setText(text1 + var1 + text2 + var2);
```

It works yes but in fact my `TextView` are very long so I don't think my way is really appropriate.

Can i have some advice ?

Comment: "It works yes but in fact my TextView are very long so I don't think my way is really appropriate." - Can you clarify this?

Comment: @salmanwahed he is mean text is not fit to all screen in single row.

Comment: Well for exemple, my TextView contains about 50 words...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use String.format(String format, Object... args)

```java
String sex = preferences.getString("sex", "null");
String city = preferences.getString("city", "null");
String str = String.format("Hello I am a %s and I live in %s", sex, city);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(str);
```

Note - Avoid concatenation in TextView.setText()

Comment: Is it possible to define format string inside strings.xml, instead of writing it directly in the code? I want my app to keep working on different locales.

Comment: @mahdi yes you can do that. Put the string in the string.xml and replace the first '%s' with '%1$s' and the second '%s' with '%2$s'

Answer (score 0):

If Text-view is really long then you should be try this.

```
String var1= preferences.getString("sex", "null");
String var2= preferences.getString("city", "null");

Text.setText("Hello I am a"+var1+"\n"+"I live in"+var2);
```

This is good way Present Text in Text View